# Set Apache HTTP header except for specified URL

Tags: apache-2.2, http, cgi, http-headers

I'm using [Apache 2.2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2) and want to set the [X-Frame-Options](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2009/01/27/ie8-security-part-vii-clickjacking-defenses.aspx) header to "deny" across most of the site.  I can turn it on unconditionally using [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html).  However, there is one CGI scripts that returns content that has to be framed, so I need to turn it off for that script.  Is there a way to do this?

I'm using Debian's Apache 2.2.9.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using the [SetEnvIf](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html) directive, coupled with `env` in your `Header` directive:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/MyCGI" is_cgi
Header set X-Frame-Options some-value env=!is_cgi
```

(or something close to that :-))

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `Location` directive.

```
<Location /url/fragment/to/my/cgi/script>
  Header unset X-Frame-Options
</Location>
```

Comment: I want "set header for everything EXCEPT this one CGI."  I think your code does "set header for JUST this one CGI"?

Comment: user9876, Sorry for the misunderstanding, I have updated the question